# Infinite loop in Excel VBA reading current folder for files

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I can't debug the following code.

```
Sub ElaboraFilesPianoFerie()
    Dim directoryPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wsOrigine As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestinazione As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    ' Imposta la directory corrente
    directoryPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    ' Ottiene il primo file nella directory con "Piano Ferie" nel nome
    fileName = Dir(directoryPath & "*Piano Ferie*.xl*")


    
    ' Elabora ogni file corrispondente ai criteri
    Do While fileName <> ""
    
    ' Verifica se il file contiene "Piano Ferie" ma non "Piano Ferie Globale"
     If InStr(1, fileName, "Piano Ferie Globale", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      
      If InStr(1, fileName, "Piano Ferie ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    
        ' Verifica se il file è aperto
        Set wsOrigine = Nothing
        For Each wb In Workbooks
            If wb.Name = fileName Then
                Set wsOrigine = wb.Sheets("PIANO FERIE")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next wb

        If wsOrigine Is Nothing Then
            ' Il file non è aperto, prova ad aprirlo
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(directoryPath & fileName)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If wb Is Nothing Then
                ' Se il file non può essere aperto, mostra un messaggio di errore
                MsgBox "Impossibile aprire il file '" & fileName & "'.", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Set wsOrigine = wb.Sheets("PIANO FERIE")


        End If

        ' Controlla se la cella H8 nel foglio di origine
        If wsOrigine.Range("H8").Value = "OK" Then
            ' Controlla se il foglio "TEMP" esiste già e, in caso affermativo, eliminatelo
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEMP")
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not wsTemp Is Nothing Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Disabilita gli avvisi per eliminare il foglio
                wsTemp.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

            ' Crea un nuovo foglio "TEMP"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDestinazione = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If wsDestinazione Is Nothing Then
                ' Se il foglio non può essere creato, mostra un messaggio di errore
                MsgBox "Impossibile creare un nuovo foglio.", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If

            wsDestinazione.Name = "TEMP"

            ' Copia e incolla il contenuto
            wsOrigine.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wsDestinazione.Range("A1")

            ' Pulisce la clipboard
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            ' Chiusura del file dopo l'elaborazione
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            
        Else
            MsgBox "Il file " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Chr(34) & fileName & Chr(34) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " non ha dati validi. Proseguo con i file successivi.", vbExclamation
        End If

        ' Ottiene il nome del prossimo file nella directory
        fileName = Dir
   End If
  End If
Loop
    
End Sub
```

It never exits the loop and I don't understand why.
The folder contains just 3 files matching "Piano Ferie" and "Piano Ferie Globale" is the file where the macro runs. For the moment I just need to be able to open the matching files, later I'll work on the data I'm trying to copy in the TEMP sheet of "Piano Ferie Globale".

Comment: fileName = Dir, should be just before loop. Now the if is not true and the next file does not get read..

Comment: Think @Aldert meant to put that last `fileName = Dir` outside/just past the `End If`'s so it happens regardless of what happened in the If clauses.

Comment: It's all the same: below ('after') **the last** `End If` or above ('before') the `Loop`.

Comment: In the future indent the code properly and get rid of the excessive blank lines, and you will easily figure it out on your own.